# PHP: Using scandir(), folders are treated as files

Tags: php, scandir

Using PHP 5.3.3 (stable) on Linux CentOS 5.5.

Here's my folder structure:

```
www/myFolder/
www/myFolder/testFolder/
www/myFolder/testFile.txt
```

Using scandir() against the "myFolder" folder I get the following results:

```
.
..
testFolder
testFile.txt
```

I'm trying to filter out the folders from the results and only return files:

```
$scan = scandir('myFolder');

foreach($scan as $file)
{
    if (!is_dir($file))
    {
        echo $file.'\n';
    }
}
```

The expected results are:

```
testFile.txt
```

However I'm actually seeing:

```
testFile.txt
testFolder
```

Can anyone tell me what's going wrong here please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to change directory or append it to your test. `is_dir` returns false when the file doesn't exist.

```
$scan = scandir('myFolder');

foreach($scan as $file)
{
    if (!is_dir("myFolder/$file"))
    {
        echo $file.'\n';
    }
}
```

That should do the right thing

Comment: Or you could use as well is_file() function to follow a positive logic. Ex : if(is_file("myFolder/".$file)) { // do smthing }

Answer (score 2):

Doesn't is_dir() take a file as a parameter?

```
$scan = scandir('myFolder');

foreach($scan as $file)
{
    if (!is_dir($file))
    {
        echo $file.'\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: The parameter of `is_dir` is a *relative* filename! So this is NOT correct, you should pass myFolder too (e.g. `is_dir('myFolder/'.$file)`) like in Cfreak's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353853/php-using-scandir-folders-are-treated-as-files/3353903#3353903).

Answer (score 2):

Already told you the answer here: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52471

Comment: You did, but I thought your answer was a bit vague without an example to back it up. Nevertheless I can see where I've gone wrong now (thanks to the examples above) and understand what you mean.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, sorry for all the bug reports today. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you were displaying errors, you'd see why this isn't working:

```
Warning: Wrong parameter count for is_dir() in testFile.php on line 16
```

Now try passing $file to is_dir()

```
$scan = scandir('myFolder'); 

foreach($scan as $file) 
{ 
    if (!is_dir($file)) 
    { 
        echo $file.'\n'; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone who comes here is interested in saving the output to an array, here's a fast way of doing that (modified to be more efficient):

```
$dirPath = 'dashboard';

$dir = scandir($dirPath);

foreach($dir as $index => &$item)
{
    if(is_dir($dirPath. '/' . $item))
    {
        unset($dir[$index]);
    }
}

$dir = array_values($dir);
```