# PHP function 'scandir' not working on WordPress hosted on windows

Tags: php, windows, wordpress

When i am using scandir function i get different  results on linux and windows.

Windows i see only folder name

Linux it does the job under

I run a check if WordPress files has been changed ?

```
function find_all_files($dir, $deep) 
{ 
  if(strpos($dir,"wp-content") == false){

    $root = scandir($dir); 
    foreach($root as $value) 
    { 
      if($value === '.' || $value === '..') {continue;} 
      if(is_file("$dir/$value")) {
            $tmpFile = "$dir/$value";
            if(5000000>@filesize($tmpFile)){

            $result[]="$tmpFile";
            }
            continue;
        } 

    $tmp = "$dir/$value";
      if(strpos($tmp,"wp-content") == false){   
        if($deep == true){
            foreach(@$this->find_all_files("$dir/$value",true) as $value) 
            { 
              $tmpFile = $value;
                  if(5000000>@filesize($tmpFile)){

                    $result[]="$tmpFile"; 
                    }
            } 
        }
      }
    }
    //var_dump($result);

    return $result; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `scandir` return? Please take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3353853/php-using-scandir-folders-are-treated-as-files

Comment: Return only folder names could be the reason  "User has no access to filesystem" tnx

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and it all came down to:

**1)** if you mean "running on windows" **OS** you need to include, and start from **the drive directory** (where server is installed) in `$dir` to scan.

**2)** Windows might be picky about separators, compare your $dir with Wordpress `ABSPATH` and try to use PHP constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` instead of your own `'/'` separators.

**3)** And I asume you working with paths, **not** urls `(http://localhost/wordpress/...plugin/dir/)`. This is working for me on Windows 7, running Uniserver (LAMP):

```
$rootfolder = 'startfolder';
$dir = plugin_dir_path(dirname( __FILE__ )).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$rootfolder;
$files = array_slice(scandir($dir), 2);
```

**However**, you need to cut down the path end begin in the install dir with `ABSPATH` or something. But I recommend to test where your filescript is, like plugins folder, to not consume a huge stall on errors while working with this kind of stuff.

**Hint!**
The PHP docs about scandir has a lot off contributed functions about reading, retriving, scanning functions and issues. Take a look at: http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php

**Important!**
Do not start messing with windows folder access, and if you do, take a RAW copy of whole www directory first, otherwise exported Worpdress installs *could get messy* on a Apache server live.

> Remember, did you manage to install a new plugin from the Wordpress
>   admin, you propably dont have a folder access issue.

Hop this helps!